# Vagrant box log file

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant 1.9.5 (не знаю как другие версии) в одной директории с боксом создаёт log-файл, у меня он называется `ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log`. Мне нужно, чтобы лог лежал в другом месте (`/var/logs/`). Вопрос - где это настраивается (в `Vagrantfile`?) и как? Из названия файла видно, что лог этот относится к конкретному боксу, значит, настраиваться по идее должен внутри `Vagrantfile`. Но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это настраивается в самом VirtualBox. Виртуальная машина выключена, заходим в её настройки, идём на вкладку `COM-порты` и видим, что `Порт 1` у нас вкл и в самом низу в строке `Путь/адрес` прописано как раз то, на что ругается Vagrant. Меняем этот путь на тот, где у нас теперь живёт наш бокс, и всё становится хорошо.